# Javadoc loading slows down Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, spring-tool-suite

Whenever the JavaDoc tooltip is loading while

a) hovering the cursor over an Object

b) or using the code assistant (autocomplete)

it takes up to 1 second until i can continue typing. It does not happen immediately after start, but after using STS/Eclipse for a while. Then i have to restart it again to get rid of the problem.

What i notice aswell is the high CPU usage (25%) even STS is running in background and not beeing used.

[image: STS CPU usage idle]

Following errors have been logged:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:347)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
        at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.LSPTextHover.getHoverInfo(LSPTextHover.java:109)
        at org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.jdt.SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.getHoverInfo2(SpringBootJavaHoverProvider.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)



!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2019-09-24 11:14:07.629
!MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.resolve(UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.getAnnotationType(UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding.filterTypeAnnotations(MethodBinding.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding.getAnnotations(MethodBinding.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getAnnotations(JavadocHover.java:1192)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.addAnnotations(JavadocHover.java:1149)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:757)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:169)
```

What i have tried already:

I disabled already the "Combined Hover" under "Preferences/Java/Editor/Hovers" which solved problem a).

I enabled under "Preferences/Maven/Download Artifact Javadoc". All Javadocs should be available offline and thus load extremly fast. But they are loading slow.

The constant freezing/loading while typing and using the code assitant is still annoying.

Is there a way to disable the javadoc for the content assistant? Or is there any workaround to speed up the JavaDoc loading time? I have no explanation why it takes so much time to show up the javadoc tooltip. Where is it loaded from? If its loaded offline it should load fast.

I am using STS v4.4 which is based on Eclipse Platform v4.13.0 with OpenJ9 JDK11.

Comment: You should check where it's getting the JavaDoc from. Make sure the JDK you are working with includes the Javadoc and that Eclipse has it set as Javadoc source.

Comment: if that doesn't help, we might need to investigate this in more detail via a bug report at http://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues - in that case it would be super helpful if you could provide a few steps how to reproduce this, maybe a sample project, or a few thread dumps from the moment it is slow.

Comment: @MartinLippert. Thx for your help. Unfortunately i am not able to reproduce it. I was hoping to get some technical details how  and from where the javadoc is loaded and what could slow down this process.

Comment: @MartinLippert now i disabled the Language Servers for Java Source Files. So far its running fine for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `Language Server` is slowing down the code completion. I disabled the `Language Server` under "Preferences / Language Servers". The freezing while typing is gone.

I will make a bug report once i can 100% confirm this is the reason for the freezing.

Comment: yes, please file a bug report that, we definitely need to fix that. It is a no-go for us to slow down or cause freezes in the java editing experience caused by the language server. That should NEVER happen.

Comment: maybe this is related (or the same underlying issue) than this: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/370 - can you double check?

Comment: @MartinLippert. Its really hard to tell.I made a quick test. And it feels like hovering with pressed CTRL-Button is a bit slower while language server (java source files) is enabled. As i mentioned above, the combined hover is affected aswell, so i can imagine CTRL+click is also affected. the bug is not reproduceable in short time. it feels like that STS gets slower over time while java source file language server is enabled.

Comment: It would be super awesome if you could attach maybe a profiler to the language server process once it hits the point that your IDE got remarkably slower and collect some profiling data, maybe a heap snapshot, etc. Maybe there is a memory leak that is causing GC to take over the CPU cycles or something like that...

Comment: @MartinLippert, i will have time in around 1 week. i would like to help you. but i need more instruction how to perform this snapshots. i made a quick test with jprofiler and visualvm, but eclipse/sts is not listed there. jconsole has multiple options to attach, i dont know where to attach. i dont see any dumping options in jconsole. we can continue the discussion on the github issue.